# Mask password in JSON to be imported by PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I'm importing values from JSON to PowerShell to use it as a connection string to SQL.

Here is the current JSON file I've:

```
{
    "Databases": [{
            "InstanceName": "test-01\\ins01",
            "DatabaseName": "test_logs",
            "User": "dba",
                        "Password": "P@ssw0rd"
        }   
    ]
}
```

Since one of these values is a password. I'd like to know how can I mask the password in the JSON file in the meantime stay able to retrieve it in PowerShell?

Comment: take a look at `Get-Help ConvertTo-SecureString -Detailed`. you would need to convert the value _before_ putting it in the JSON if you use that method.

Comment: where does the json come from? Are you creating it with powershell?

Comment: I create the JSON manually and allocate these values on it. It's not an output file. I used it as an input for my PowerShell varibles

Comment: Beware that encryption of secure strings is tied to the computer and account creating them (meaning they're not portable). And they aren't as secure as their name may lead you to believe. Normally it should be sufficiently secure to restrict access to the JSON file via filesystem ACLs.

Comment: You _can_ make it portable by using the `ConvertTo-SecureString` together with the `-Key` parameter. See [this blog](https://www.pdq.com/blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-2/) on how to do that.

Comment: I know that, but I want to mask it in JSON then import it to powershell not to convert it with PowerShell

Comment: @Theo But then you'd need to store the key in clear text somewhere, which kind of defeats the purpose of using secure strings in the first place.

Comment: @MohamedWaly That is not possible since JSON is a plain text format.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yes, that's true. I just wanted to point out that using `-Key` you can get past the restriction of the securestring being only valid for the same user on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

As that was being said before, you will have to use the ConvertFrom-SecureString & ConvertTo-SecureString powershell cmdlets.

Around this, there is 2 methods:

First idea, [as explained on this blog](https://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/powershell/5396/storing-powershell-credentials-in-json/), is to directly store the secured password to your Json file, like this:

```
$secure = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'P@$$w0rd' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -typename PSCredential -ArgumentList @('company\admin',$secure)
$cred | Select Username,@{Name="Password";Expression = { $_.password | ConvertFrom-SecureString }} |  Convertto-Json
```

And then convert the secured password back from your JSON file:

```
$file = Get-Content -Path c:\temp\admin.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$secure = ConvertTo-SecureString $file.Password -ErrorAction Stop
```

But you will be abble to uncrypt the SecureString only on the same computer.

So the 2nd method is to use the ConvertTo-SecureString and specify an AES file, as it's well explained [on this other blog](https://www.pdq.com/blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-2/).

So, basically you create the AES file:

```
$KeyFile = "C:\AES.key"
$Key = New-Object Byte[] 16   # You can use 16, 24, or 32 for AES
[Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create().GetBytes($Key)
$Key | out-file $KeyFile
```

And you store the secured password in your json, like above but with the -Key option:

```
$cred | Select Username,@{Name="Password";Expression = { $_.password | ConvertFrom-SecureString }} -key $Key | Convertto-Json
```

And the same way to revert back the secured password:

```
$secure = ConvertTo-SecureString $file.Password -Key $key -ErrorAction Stop
```

Hope this help.